# Calling other functions in the same class gets "Can't find variable" in ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

I'm using ionic 2 to build an app, and I have this code:

```
export class LoginPage {
    constructor(...) {...}
    jump() {...}
    authenticate() {
        jump();
    }
}
```

But when I run it, I got **Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jump**. The authenticate() works well when I call it from the .html (click). This is my first time using ionic 2 and angular js, please help this rookie out lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export class LoginPage {
    constructor(...) {...}
    jump() {...}
    authenticate() {
        this.jump();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, use **this.jump()** and also mind what **this** is referring to.